# How to prevent git from tracking a new branch to the parent local branch?

Tags: git

Today my git has decided to automatically track the parent local branch whenever I do `git checkout -b`. For example:

```
(master) $ git checkout -b test
Branch test set up to track local branch master.
Switched to a new branch 'test'
(test) $
```

Why is it suddenly doing this? I don't have this issue on any of my other systems, and I haven't recently modified my .gitconfig file.
I update my git version from 1.9.1 to 2.4.5 and the same thing happens.

Comment: I would recommend to show us your configuration. Especially the config entry *branch.setupautomerge*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading the man pages I found out that the culprit is actually

```
[branch]
autosetupmerge = always
```

in my .gitconfig.

I don't even remember why I added this option in the first place.

Comment: Yes, I was expecting something like this. So this is why git acting like this.